# The same results in spite of the different amount of the same parameter

Tags: python, sumo

I want to examine the effect of changing the amount of a specific parameter (e.g. tau, accel, decel, sigma) over the flow characteristics via 2 iterations. So, I use the following python script and TraCI tools in which the tau variations are observed:

```
import traci

tau = [3, 4]
n = 2
for i in range(n):
    def run():
        traci.start(sumoCmd)
        traci.vehicle.add('vehicle_2', 'route_1', 'emergency', '45')
        for j in tau:
            traci.vehicle.setTau('vehicle_2', j)                    
        N = 200
        step = 0
        for step in range(N):     
            traci.simulationStep()               
            step += 1
        traci.close()
        sys.stdout.flush()
          
     run()
```

At the end of the simulation, the results are not different and it makes me think that there is something wrong with my code. I would be thankful if you could help me.
Best regards,
Ali

Comment: You set tau in a loop, but wouldn't tau then just have the last value in the following code?

Comment: … also, you run the same code twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main loop should be over `tau`, not the inner loop.

You should also just define the function once, and pass `j` as a parameter.

```
import traci

tau = [3, 4]

def run(j):
    traci.start(sumoCmd)
    traci.vehicle.add('vehicle_2', 'route_1', 'emergency', '45')
    traci.vehicle.setTau('vehicle_2', j)                    
    N = 200
    step = 0
    for step in range(N):     
        traci.simulationStep()               
    traci.close()
    sys.stdout.flush()

for j in tau:
```

There's no need for `step += 1`. The `for` loop increments it automatically.

Comment: Thank you, Barmar. It works very well.